# Get Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm trying to add an active class to the active menu link, but unable to do so with jquery. I am using the  [responsive mean menu.](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus)

This is my first time ever using jquery, and I am probably missing something that is quite obvious. I have made a .js file in a "scripts" folder in my theme directory and added it through the theme.info file. I have and tried many different jquery codes to try to add it, adding the code in many tutorials with no success.

Here are just some:

- css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/
- stackoverflow.com/questions/26838904/cant-add-active-class-to-parent-li-tab-upon-child-li-clicked
- codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/lGALt
- (no links because of lack of reputation :)

  However, every time I add the jquery, I get this error:

  ```
  Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
  ```

This is the entire code in the mytheme.js file:

```
/* Add active class to current menu link */
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mean-bar .mean-nav li a').click(function(){
   $('.mean-bar .mean-nav li a').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
/* ".mean-bar .mean-nav li a" */
```

Comment: Add jquery library to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, quite a while later, I have discovered that Drupal requires your first statement to be written like this:

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($){...});`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't referenced jquery in your page.

i.e.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: make sure you include this script before using $ in your html file. so the first script tag to get jquery on your page. and second script tag to use $ or other jquery functions.

Comment: Jquery update doesn't suffice? I have also added the code into my page.tpl.php, but still doesn't work.